# Using chain rule to find the derivative of $(4x^2-2)^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I just took a quiz and one of the problems was to get the derivative of $f(x) = (4x^2-2)^3$.

I used the chain rule and got $f'(x) = 24x(4x^2-2)^2$.

However, plugging it into the derivative function in a TI-89 returns 
$f(x) = 96x(2x^2-1)^2$. Which is right? Me or the calculator?

Comment: Both are right, they are the same. The TI "simplified" a little more than you did.

Comment: Calculators should get banned..

Comment: @AhmedHussein: I might not go as far as you, but certainly they should not be allowed on tests. Student performance would improve.

Comment: Just stupid reasoning from me. Sorry! Might as well leave this up as a totem to my stupidity.

Comment: Well, if the calculator said f(x) and *not* f'(x) then you are.  But if the calculator said f'(x) then both are right and you *really* should have imediately noticed $48x(4x^2 - 2)^2 = 48x(2(2x^2 - 1))^2 = 48x4(2x^2 + 1)^2 = 96x(2x^2 + 1)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y' = 24x(4x^2-2)^2$$
$$y'=24x[2(2x^2-1)]^2$$
$$y'=24x[2^2(2x^2-1)^2]$$
$$y'=96x(2x^2-1)^2$$
both are right